# Using GoogleAPI with LibGDX on eclipse: GameHelper could not be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx, google-api-client

I'm trying to use the Google API Client for games (namely the BasicGameUtils package) on my LibGDX project setup. I've been following this tutorial http://fortheloss.org/tutorial-set-up-google-services-with-libgdx/#comment-4130 .
My current problem is that when I try to implement the GameHelper object, it doesnt seem to find itself "imported" into the project, even though I've set up everything like that guide said. The following code

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements IGoogleServices {
        private GameHelper _gameHelper;
        protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

gives an error in `private GameHelper _gameHelper;` line stating: "GameHelper cannot be resolved to a type".
This is in the file: AndroidLauncher.java, using Libgdx version 1.6.4.
Thanks in advance and sorry if I made any mistakes asking this question. This is my first question ever in StackOverflow even though I found answers to my code problems here for the past 8 years.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of BaseGameUtils is not compiled as dependency. Let's get through it:

- Make sure you have BaseGameUtils as a module. Which needs to be a BaseGameUtils folder besides android, core in your project folder. And following line in settings.gradle at the root of your project folder:

  ```
  include 'desktop', 'android', 'ios', 'core', 'BaseGameUtils'
  ```
- Then you need to compile your BaseGameUtils module as a dependency to your android module. So your build.gradle at the root of your project folder should look like this:

  ```
  ...

  project(":android") {
      apply plugin: "android"

      configurations { natives }

      dependencies {
          compile project(":core")
          ...
          //google play game services
          compile project(":BaseGameUtils")
      }

      ...
  ```

I am not mentioned about GooglePlayGameServices libraries which are needed also for a working integration but not relevant to recognition of GameHelper class.

Comment: This was actually missing in the project. I added it.
The bug although is still there. It doesnt recignize the GameHelper class.
Also if you could elavorate about GooglePlayGameServices would be great. About this, I have set up everything for "google-play-services_lib" as a library linked to the BaseGameUtils library. So if you could tell me if im missing something about GooglePlayGameServices, would be very helpful aswell. Again, I've done what you said but the GameHelper class is still not recognized.

Comment: Ive also added this `import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.*;` just in case. But it made no difference

Comment: did you synced/refreshed gradle after those changes?

Comment: no. i did now but still no changes. refreshed all on all the projects with gradle finishing with refreshing the gradle on the main project. problem persist.

Comment: more info. the project setup is this: a project called BaseGameUtils, isLibrary in android properties. another project called google-play-services_lib also configured as isLib. Both added to the android project of the game as Dependencies. Now with Burak answer i have added both to build.gradle and settings.gradle like he mentioned.
Wether or not doing this with the google-play-services_lib is wrong, Ive done it with BaseGameUtils and it still doesnt recognize the GameHelper class. I serioulsy dont know whats wrong here. These kind of project setup bugs are quite annoying.

Comment: i restarted the Eclipse IDE and the following errors show up when loading the projects: Configuration with name 'default' not found.
Could not fetch model of type 'EclipseProject' using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2-all.zip'.  I must admit im a big Gradle Noob.

Comment: if its not a problem for you could you upload your source code?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be an actual answer to the question, but its an answer to my problem.
I migrated to Android Studio <<<
Only thing i needed to do was to remove BaseGameUtils from the project, add it fresh on the Android Studio. voila.
Naturally i had to add it to the compile options on android gradle and imports.
Not going back to eclipse for android at least.
Thanks for your help btw Burak.